# How to only update one column in pinned objects in Parse local storage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform

In docs it says that `When an object is pinned, every time you update it by fetching or saving new data, the copy in the local datastore will be updated automatically.`

But what if I only want to update only one column(one key) without having to fetch the entire data object? Is it possible?